# Expand border-top from center on hover

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate yellow bar like it the one on border-bottom. (and I want to get rid of the border bottom I just putted it for example

http://jsfiddle.net/9mfccz6w/1/

```
.navbar  li{
    display: inline-block;
   border-width:5px;    
   border-top-style:solid;
   border-top-color: white;
}

.navbar li:hover, .navbar li:active{
   border-width:4px;    
   border-top-style:solid;
   border-top-color: #e0b82b;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-2px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-2px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-2px);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
```

Thank you

Comment: The answer posted work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you are using `:after` use `:before`, your code should be:

```
.navbar li:before, .navbar li:after{
  display: block;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.0001);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0.0001);
  transform: scaleX(0.0001);  
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.navbar li:before{
  border-top: solid 3px #e0b82b;
}
.navbar li:after{
  border-bottom: solid 3px #019fb6;
}
.navbar li:hover:before, .navbar li:hover:after{
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9mfccz6w/4/)

Note: I also remove `border-top-color: #e0b82b;` on `.navbar li:hover, .navbar li:active`. Maybe you want to make a few more changes ;)